# Melee champion attack range?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which champions (melee) have an auto attack range more than 125? So far I only know that wukong has an AA range of 175

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum range for melee champions is not really 175. It usually ranges from 125 to 175, but can be greater in some situations. Here is a ordered list of ranges for melee champions in League of Legends :

- Rengar (with [Unseen Predator](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rengar#Unseen_Predator) and 9 trophies on his [Bonetooth Necklace](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Bonetooth_Necklace)) = 750
- Rengar (with [Unseen Predator](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rengar#Unseen_Predator)) = 650
- Hecarim (with [Devastating Charge](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hecarim#Devastating_Charge)) = 325
- Wukong (with [Crushing Blow](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Wukong#Crushing_Blow)) = 300
- Riven (with [Blade of The Exile](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Riven#Blade_of_the_Exile)) = 200
- Cho'Gath (with Rank 3 [Feast](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cho%27Gath#Feast) at 6 stacks), Fizz, Hecarim, Jarvan IV, Kha'Zix (with Evolved [Taste Their Fear](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kha%27Zix#Taste_Their_Fear)), Nasus (with active [Fury Of The Sands](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nasus#Fury_of_the_Sands)), Nautilus, Vi (with [Excessive Force](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vi#Excessive_Force)), Wukong, Xin Zhao = 175
- Diana, Pantheon = 150
- Darius (with [Crippling Strike](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ability#Crippling_Strike)) = 145
- Akali, Alistar, Amumu, Blitzcrank, Cho'Gath, Darius, Dr.Mundo, Elise (with [Spider Form](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elise#Spider_Form)), Evelynn, Fiora, Galio, Gangplank, Garen, Gragas, Irelia, Jax, Jayce (with [Transform : Mercury Hammer](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Jayce#Transform:_Mercury_Hammer)), Kassadin, Katarina, Kayle, Kha'Zix, Lee Sin, Leona, Malphite, Maokai, Master Yi, Mordekaiser, Nasus, Nidalee (with [Aspect Of The Cougar](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nidalee#Aspect_Of_The_Cougar)), Nocturne, Nunu, Olaf, Poppy, Rammus, Renekton, Rengar, Riven, Rumble, Sejuani, Shaco, Shen, Shyvana, Singed, Sion, Skarner, Talon, Taric, Trundle, Tryndamere, Udyr, Valor, Vi, Volibear, Yorick, Warwick, Zed = 125

Sources :

- Mainly the [Range article on LoL's wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Range)
- A fair bit of testing and checking

Comment: For comparison, Caitlin's basic attack have a range of 650

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz Please choose an easier name next time x) Also, don't leave this question unanswered if my answer is what you were looking for. Mark it as the answer so that it doesn't stay in the Unanswered tab (or any other eventual answer if you don't like mine).

Comment: ok calm,i just got back home.

Comment: Note that Darius's Crippling Strike, Wukong's crushing blow and Hecarim's Devastating Charge, being usually used in chases, have a bonus range for their characters =) It's sometimes not obvious at all, especially for Darius, with whom you should use this skill before autoattacking when closing on someone since you'll hit earlier AND you'll slow your target.